# Integrating df(x)

Tags: calculus

I have a question regarding integration that popped up while I was studying, is the antiderivative of df(x) the function f(x) itself ? If yes how does that work in terms of differentiating a function so it only equals its own differential?

Comment: This may be an informal way to state $\int_a^b df(x) = f(b)-f(a)$.  In case $f$ is not differentiable, see "Stieltjes integral".

Answer (score 0):

Whether the integral exists is the first thing you need to determine.  As stated in the comments, the integral:

$$\int df(x) $$

Is a Steiltjes integral (sometimes "Riemann-Steiltjes Integral" to differentiate it from the "Lebesgue-Steiltjes Integral").  In general such an integral would be written as:

$$\int g(x) df(x)$$

Now, whether this integral exists is not a simple matter, but here is a sufficient condition:  Presuming that $g$ is continuous and $\frac{df}{dx}$ is Riemann integrable, then the integral exists.  In your case, $g = 1$ is continuous so the answer boils down to the properties of $f(x)$, which in general wouldn't be Riemann integrable.

Presuming that it is, your integral becomes:

$$\int f'(x) dx$$

And your statement is correct.  However, like I said, it all depends on what $f$ is doing.